# International (or European) life insurance?

Tags: eu, insurance

I'm an academic and I find myself moving from country to country every couple years (EU + Switzerland). I would like to take a life insurance (death/disability) that will cover me when I move. This is for my family, in case something happens to me. Do you know of such an insurance?

Comment: I would think any regional insurance plan with a re-patriotation clause would do the trick.